# Using .tagName correctly

Tags: javascript, nodes

```
if (((document.activeElement).parentNode).tagName == "div") { 
   //do amazing things 
}
```

For some reason a specific function of mine isn't working, and I think it has to do with the line above.  Is the line above syntactically correct, or is wrong?  If the line above is correct, I'll either delete the question (because then the question is useless) or add additional information of the rest of the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tagName gives the tag in upper-case so it would give `DIV`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.tagName

You can use `.toLowerCase() == 'div'`(as suggested in the comments) to eliminate the case issue.

Comment: @Hubrid: `tagName` is a string, so `'DIV'`. You can also convert it to lowercase though: `.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div'`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all the parens. To be safe, use `tagName.toLowerCase()`.

```
if (document.activeElement.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") { 
   //do amazing things 
}
```

There may be some browsers that sometimes do not give the same case as others. This makes sure you always compare the same case.

Comment: ty's for saying you don't need all the parens, wasn't sure about thast either.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of HTML, the value in the `tagName` field is always uppercase.
However, if you run this script in XML/XHTML context, it will return the name of the tag exactly as provided (and not necessarily uppercase).

Try calling `document.activeElement.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase()` to make it always lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (((document.activeElement).parentNode).tagName === "DIV") { 
   //do amazing things 
}
```